# Probing the assembly from parent directory of the exe

Tags: c#, winforms, probing

i have a folder structure as IntegrationClient\SampleClient\Client.Exe. I have created a folder DrawingClient with lot of thirdparty assemblies. For client.exe to find the assembly at runtime , i have used probing path as below and it works.

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <probing privatePath="bin;DrawingClient;"/>
</assemblyBinding>
```

But if i need the client.exe to find the DrawingClient folder from parent directory ie under IntegrationClient\DrawingClient, can i achieve that by any means ? I tried using ..\DrawingClient however that failed.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, you cannot...

The [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w(v=vs.110).aspx) states that `privatePath` *[...] [s]pecifies **subdirectories** of the application's base directory that might contain assemblies. [...]*

Answer (score -3):

Firstly I'm pretty sure you have to use forward slashes rather than backslashes.

In addition to that you can chain your `../` lookups as far back up the directory tree you need to go

Example:

this `../`  is the Parent Directory and this
`../../` is the Grand-Parent directory and so forth...

Comment: forward slashes too didn't help .